# Is there a way to grab a specific text from a CSS selector?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im looking to grab all the #text portion of a css selector when inspecting an element. I seem to be grabbing all numbers under my selector instead of the text portion.

The Link im scraping is https://www.virginmobile.ca/en/phones/phone-details.html#!/gs9/Grey/64/TR20.

I would like to grab the prices under 'pick your phone price' but without the '$' and '99' cents at the end of the string

Currently Im only familiar with grabbing the entire String.

```
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(3)
    print('---------------------------  begining ------------------')

    planTypeUpfrontCostListRaw = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#phonePricesList .ultra')))

    for element in planTypeUpfrontCostListRaw:
        upfrontCost = element.text
        print(upfrontCost)

    print('---------------------------  END  ------------------------')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**
Instead of using `text`, use `innerHTML`. This will returns you the html code of that element including the text!

For example, it will return you:

```
"<sup>$</sup>199<sup>99</sup>"
```

Then you can use the regex library `re` to get the value in the middle only.

```
print(re.search('\d+', upfrontCost).group(0))
```

Output: `199`
**Here's the code to do so:**

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import re

link = "https://www.virginmobile.ca/en/phones/phone-details.html#!/gs9/Grey/64/TR20"
driver = Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
driver.get(link)
print('---------------------------  begining ------------------')

planTypeUpfrontCostListRaw = wait.until \
    (EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.price.ultra.ng-binding.ng-scope')))

for element in planTypeUpfrontCostListRaw:
     upfrontCost = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
     upfrontCost = re.search('\d+', upfrontCost).group(0)
     print(upfrontCost)
print('---------------------------  END  ------------------------')
```

**Output:**

```
---------------------------  begining ------------------
0
0
199
349
739
1019
---------------------------  END  ------------------------
```

**Solution2**
You can still use `text` and remove the unwanted data using `strip` for the $ and remove last two digit.

```
driver = Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
driver.get(link)
print('---------------------------  begining ------------------')

planTypeUpfrontCostListRaw = wait.until \
    (EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.price.ultra.ng-binding.ng-scope')))

for element in planTypeUpfrontCostListRaw:
     upfrontCost = element.text.strip('$')
     if upfrontCost != '0':
         upfrontCost = upfrontCost[:-2]
     print(upfrontCost)
print('---------------------------  END  ------------------------')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could dump into bs4 and use stripped_strings

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

d = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\chromedriver.exe')
d.get('https://www.virginmobile.ca/en/phones/phone-details.html?province=ON&geoResult=failed#!/gs9/Grey/64/TR20')
WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "planlevels .price")))
soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
plans = soup.select('planlevels .price')

for plan in plans:
    price = [string for string in plan.stripped_strings][1]
    print(price)
```

---

Uglier, IMO, could be to use split and no BS4

```
plans = WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "planlevels .price")))
for plan in plans:
    print(plan.get_attribute('innerHTML').split('</sup>')[1].split('<sup>')[0])
```